# help setting up a velocity question

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

> Standing on the ground from 3.0 m from a building, you want to throw a package from your 1.5- shoulder level to someone in a window 4.2 m above the ground. At what speed and angle should you throw the package so it just barely clears the window sill?

So first I set up my parameters:

```
initial x=0
initial y=1.5
x velocity=?
y velocity= 0
x acceleration=0
y acceleration=-9.8m/s^2
final x=3.0 m
final y= 2.7 m (4.2-1.5)
final x velocity=?
final y velocity=0 
t=.93s (I found this by solving the equation y=1/2at^2+vt)
```

are my parameters correct, if not where did I go wrong?

Comment: Based on your parameters, the equation at the end should be of the form $\Delta y=-4.9t^2+(0)t$ which as no solutions in $t$. Physically, that stems from the fact that the box can't reach the window if it isn't moving up initially. Also, you take $y_0$ relative to the ground $(1.5$ meters$)$ but $y_f$ relative to your shoulder.

Comment: how should my parameters be set up then?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your vertical displacement is $d_y = 4.2 - 1.5 = 2.7$. Now there are infinitely many parabolic trajectories that will solve the problem. To fix this, let's interpret "so it just barely clears the window sill" to mean "so that the final vertical velocity is $v_{fy} = 0$", as you correctly figured out. Then since $a_y = -9.8$ and we want to solve for the initial vertical velocity $v_{iy}$, we use the following kinematics formula:
$$
v_{fy}^2 = v_{iy}^2 + 2a_yd_y \implies
v_{iy} = \sqrt{v_{fy}^2 - 2a_yd_y}
= \sqrt{0^2 - 2(-9.8)(2.7)}
= 7.2746...
$$
We can also solve for time:
$$
v_{fy} = v_{iy} + a_yt \iff
t = \frac{v_{fy} - v_{iy}}{a}
= \frac{0 - 7.2746...}{-9.8}
= 0.7423...
$$
So we can now handle the horizontal components:
$$
v_{ix} = \frac{d_x}{t} = \frac{3.0}{0.7423...} = 4.0415...
$$
Finally, our initial velocity is:
$$
v_i = \sqrt{v_{ix}^2 + v_{iy}^2}
= \sqrt{(4.0415...)^2 + (7.2746...)^2}
\approx 8.32
$$
and our angle is:
$$
\theta = \tan^{-1}(v_{iy}/v_{ix})
= \tan^{-1}(7.2746.../4.0415...)
\approx 61^\circ
$$

Comment: what formula are you using in the beginning.. the only formulas I know are:
x=1/2at^3+vo t +xo,
v=at+vo, 
2a(x-xo)=v^2-vo

Comment: One of the main kinematics formulas for constant acceleration. See: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations

Comment: ok thank you! one final question for your first value 0.7423 the initial y velocity I keep getting m^2/s^2 for the units but shouldn't it be m/s?

Comment: The initial vertical velocity is about $v_{iy} \approx 7.2746 ~\text{m/s}$. Since it's under a square root, the $\text{m$^2$/s$^2$}$ becomes a $\text{m/s}$.